# Python 3.10: I cannot extract text from an element with Selenium 4.8.0

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-3.10

I'm trying to extract the description from a youtube channel:

```
driver.get(channel_url+"/about")
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(lambda d: d.find_element("xpath","//*[@id=\"description\"]"))
    print(myElem.text)
except TimeoutException: print("failed")
```

This is what the HTML code looks like:

```
<yt-formatted-string id="description" split-lines="" class="style-scope ytd-channel-about-metadata-renderer">
Text I want to extract
</yt-formatted-string>
```

I am using a gecko Firefox driver

The `.text` and `get_attribute("textContent")` commands both return nothing. The `get_attribute("innerHTML")` command returns an irrelevent `<path></path>` element.

I copied the xpath from my browser using Inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube has 3-4 elements having `id` `"description"` (*I dont know why."*)
You can find it if you search with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in developers tools or using the method `find_all()`
So try using full xpath as such:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

channel_url = "https://www.youtube.com/@MrBeast"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(channel_url+"/about")
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(lambda d: d.find_element("xpath",'/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer/div[1]/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-channel-about-metadata-renderer/div[1]/div[1]/yt-formatted-string[2]'))
    print(myElem.text)
except TimeoutException: print("failed")
driver.quit()
```

Or use the proper CSS selector pointing only to the single element:
(*Obviously, you can try same way with xpath too*)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

channel_url = "https://www.youtube.com/@MrBeast"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(channel_url+"/about")
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#description-container > #description'))
    print(myElem.text)
except TimeoutException: print("failed")
driver.quit()
```